# PostgreSQL extended statistics

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

I have a 1 TB read-only database where performance is critical. It's difficult to predict queries since they are dynamically generated by the users (the whole thing is basically a visualization platform atop a large collection of medical studies, and users select what they want to visualize). Queries can often be complex and involve 10+ joins. I recently learned about the extended statistics feature, but I find little information online about when best to use it (other than what's in the documentation).

The DB is pretty well normalized, but makes extensive use of materialized views which are de-normalized. Is there any performance penalty or other issue with creating extended statistics (dependency and top n) for all pairwise columns? It would result in, say, 500 statistics on some 70 tables. Time for analyze or inserts is not of relevance, only read performance. Also, is there a tool or code snippet to help me do this?

I'm using Postgresql 12 and it's optimized as far as possible w.r.t. indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to set in place a mean to monitor the stats of relevant tables and indexes counters:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW

Specially the:

```
   seq_scan bigint

   Number of sequential scans initiated on this table

   seq_tup_read bigint

   Number of live rows fetched by sequential scans

   iseq_scan bigint

   Number of sequential scans initiated on this table

   seq_tup_read bigint

   Number of live rows fetched by sequential scans

   idx_scan bigint

   Number of index scans initiated on this table

   idx_tup_fetch bigint

   Number of live rows fetched by index scansdx_scan bigint

   Number of index scans initiated on this table

   idx_tup_fetch bigint

   Number of live rows fetched by index scans
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW

```
idx_scan bigint

Number of index scans initiated on this index

idx_tup_read bigint

Number of index entries returned by scans on this index

idx_tup_fetch bigint

Number of live table rows fetched by simple index scans using this index
```